# How to set Prestashop 1.5 to ask zipcode, but not require it?

Tags: prestashop

How can I set Prestashop to ask for a zipcode, but not require it?

Set NO from Localization > Countries will delete zipcode from the form on front office.

I'm using prestashop v1.5.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way is to remove some code directly from the c3ontrollers (2 rows):

/controllers/front/AuthController.php

/controllers/front/AddressController.php

/controllers/admin/AdminAddressController.php

```
    elseif(empty($postcode) && $country->need_zip_code)
    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('A Zip / Postal code is required.');
```

Doing changes directly in controllers means that during the next upgrade of PrestaShop they will be removed, so the best approach is to use overrides:

1. Copy AuthController.php to override/controllers/front/
2. Remove all methods & properties except the one with the code above
3. Change "class AuthControllerCore extends FrontController" to "class AuthController extends AuthControllerCore "
4. Remove the "elseif" part from the "quickest way"

Do the 4 steps for all the 3 Controllers.